# Can I select both MSc in Data Science and MSc in Artificial Intelligence programs at the same time while applying for Chevening Scholarship?

Tags: data

I know that Data Science is a subset of Artificial Intelligence. So, the two Masters programs are pretty similar, as both of them teach Machine Learning. However, Artificial Intelligence program focuses on much wider topics, like Deep Learning and Big Data. Nonetheless, there are a lot of similarities.

As the two programs are quite similar, can I choose the two programs at the same time while applying for Chevening scholarship?

Right now, I have got three conditional offer letters:

1. Durham University - MSc in Data Science
2. University of Plymouth - MSc in Artificial Intelligence
3. University of Chester - MSc in Computer Science

I am looking forward to your advice on this matter.

Comment: Actually, you misunderstood my question. I don't want to study two programs at the same time. In the Chevening scholarship portal, I have two choose three universities and subjects. I am wondering if Chevening allows me to pick up both Data Science and Artificial Intelligence. Because the title of the two programs are different. But the content are pretty similar.

Comment: @Dave Do u have any idea about this matter of subject choices for Chevening scholarship?

Comment: Only the scholarship can determine that. If the degrees literally need the same name (e.g., both called "mathematics", not one called "mathematics" and another called "mathematical sciences"), then you're out of luck. I don't know the rules of this particular scholarship, but you would have to pick fairly different subjects for me to consider them different (e.g., data science and Spanish literature, though you might be able to convince me if you're interested in doing NLP on Spanish language). But I'm not involved in that scholarship, so only their opinions matter.